# How do you update an old Integrated Intel GPU's drivers to work with Steam?

Tags: 14.04, intel-graphics, steam, opengl

I am trying to play Steam games on my computer running Ubuntu 14.04. On launching Team Fortress 2 I receive the error `Cannot find required OpenGL entry point 'glGetError'! Either your video card is unsupported, or your OpenGL driver need to be updated.`

I tried `sudo rm /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so` and 
 `rm  .local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1` with no luck. What is going wrong exactly and how should I attempt to go about fixing it.

I am using integrated Intel graphics. System settings call it an `Intel® 945G x86/MMX/SSE2`.

My driver is an `Intel Open Source Technology Center Mesa DRI Intel(R) 945G x86/MMX/SSE2`

**EDIT: I ended up shelling out $50 for a graphics card and TF2 and other games run fine.**

Comment: What's your graphics card and what driver are you using?

Comment: I don't see how removing those files would help you resolve this error. I would begin by looking to see if the video card is supported, and if so updating the driver would seem the next logical step.

Comment: I believe I am using an Intel graphics card. System settings call it an `Intel® 945G x86/MMX/SSE2`. My driver is a `Intel Open Source Technology Center Mesa DRI Intel(R) 945G x86/MMX/SSE2`
. I am about to pop open my computer to check exactly what GPU I have.

Comment: It sounds like integrated graphics on the motherboard.

Comment: Yeah, your right. It turned out to be built into the mother board, the "Intel Desktop Board".

Comment: I think you need to update your kernel and the Mesa drivers. Try this approach: http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTY1NTU If it works for you I'll write it up. What tipped me off to it: http://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/495884-Upgrade-to-mesa-10-x

Comment: BTW, `Glxinfo` will show the Mesa version if you have `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils` installed. Use `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"`.

Comment: @krowe I tried the answer in the link using obiaf with no luck. `glxinfo` after following links suggestions outputted `OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 10.3.0-devel (git-faa6b0c trusty-oibaf-ppa)`.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/339476/intel-linux-graphic-drivers

Comment: @bain The install worked fine, it just didn't solve the problem at hand.

Comment: How did you install Steam?

Answer (score 2):

What is going wrong exactly:

Your video card is unsupported or your OpenGL driver needs to be updated.

How to fix it:

A) Obtain a high end supported video card - This is the solution I recommend

Minimum Required:   A DirectX 8.1 **compatible** video card

Recommended: A DirectX 9 **compatible** video card

Numerous sources found googling "Team Fortress 2 system requirements"

B) Try 2014Q2 Intel Graphics Stack Release available here:

https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2014/2014q2-intel-graphics-stack-release

Be aware that I don't believe that you will be happy with the performance provided by
the 82945G graphics for gaming which is why I personally don't recommend option B, but I'm including it here for the sake of completeness.

You may also need to reinstall the GCC support library (libgcc1) as you appear to have deleted some of it's components

Comment: Intel claims that `Intel 945G` supports DirectX 9. (http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-033757.htm#olderGraphics)

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Sorry, which do I download for B?

Comment: @Cammy_the_block Ubuntu doesn't use DirectX...

Comment: @Cammy_the_block Read Oli excellent answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/280705/update-to-latest-version-of-opengl

Comment: I still recommend A) not B)

Comment: So far I have tried installing "Graphics Installer 1.0.5 for Ubuntu* 14.04, 32-bit" (https://01.org/linuxgraphics/download) (and then running the installer) which seemed to have little impact except possibly making dash a bit faster.

Comment: Please read (or review) http://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: @ElderGeek Thanks. Are your referring to a specific action of mine that could have been more "proper", or is just that all of my performance here dreadful?

Comment: I'm referring to keeping an open mind and understanding that just because an answer isn't what you want doesn't mean it's wrong.