# How to get OpenGL 2+ support on Intel integrated graphics

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, intel, opengl

I have a laptop that has a Core Duo T2050 w. Intel® 945GM x86/MMX/SSE2 integrated graphics. I recently installed Steam and attempted to play *CS:S* and *To The Moon* and both times received a warning about OpenGL. (I know, I know. I'm not going to be able to play CS:S on a 1.60GHz processor, I was just giving it a go.)

Anyways, here's the error screen I get from CS:S :

[image: cs:s error]

and the one I get from To The Moon:

[image: To the Moon error]

Obviously, these are both OpenGL errors.

Now, I've been doing my research, but all of the results for these errors seem to be regarding NVIDIA cards, not Intel integrated graphics. All of these seemed to point to using the NVIDIA drivers solves the issue, as opposed to using Nouveau. ([Steam Forums #1](http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/1/882966056488160497/?l=english#p2), [Steam Forums #2](http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/864958088475782088/?l=czech), [GitHub - Steam for Linux](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/2044), [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123895/opengl-glsl-3-3-on-an-hd-graphics-4000-under-ubuntu-12-04).)

One other thing I'm seeing is that NVIDIA and Intel Integrated graphics can conflict, but since I *only have* Intel Integrated, I don't think this is the issue. ([Example](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/2044))

Thus, I installed the Intel Open Source drivers, and after a bit of tweaking (had to downgrade, because Intel Open Source drivers *apparently* don't like Unity) I had a system that was running just fine on Intel's drivers. However, the issue still wasn't resolved, I am still getting these errors.

One question, [from Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487729/how-do-you-update-an-old-integrated-intel-gpus-drivers-to-work-with-steam), seems to say that if you don't have OpenGL already, then your CPU/Integrated Graphics simply **can't** use OpenGL.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this issue? Is my CPU/Integrated Graphics not able to support OpenGL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your graphics chipset only supports OpenGL 1.4, according to [this post on Intel's forum](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/284458). So you will not be able to use anything which requires a newer version of OpenGL on that GPU.

Comment: Well. That *sucks*. Thanks for the answer, I was actually going to start researching the specifics of the GPU next, but didn't have the time.

Comment: FWIW, the top results for [intel 945gm opengl version](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=intel%20945gm%20opengl%20version) are all about how it doesn't support OpenGL 2.x. :)